# How can I get information about a clicked marker which was not added via overlay?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, primefaces

I have a question regarding the markers on the primefaces `gmap` element.

By now I have read up a lot about what is possible, and I found out that one can add custom markers to the map, as well as listen for their clicks and so on.

However, I want to be able to listen to clicks on one of the default markers google maps already provides.

For example:

I, as a user, would move around the map, looking for a restaurant to dine tonight. I find a marker for a restaurant I am interested in and which I want to know more about. As soon as I click it, the application - in this case my Java bean - should get information about the clicked marker.

It might not have to be all the information possible, but at least the position, name etc. so I can get information about the place with another google API.

Is there a possiblity to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Some objects within the Maps API are designed to respond to user events such as your concern with clicking a marker and getting information about the clicked marker. To achieve it, you have to integrate JavaScript which is active in the browser side with your JavaBeans which is active at server side to get the possible information for the clicked marker.

Using JavaScript, you can add interactions by generating events and add event listeners to execute code when those specified events occur.

A very good example showing how your concern can be properly achieved by adding a marker and keeping client side representation in sync with the server side model can be found in [GMap - Adding Markers](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/addMarkers.xhtml).